# How to implement dependent QuarkusTestResourceLifecycleManager

Tags: quarkus

I am trying to implement two different QuarkusTestResourceLifecycleManager for my testing. Problem is I need data from one of them in order to start the other one. For example, a resource that needs a Database server (hence it needs its recently created IP etc).

How this can be achieved? I've seen there is already a QuarkusTestResourceLifecycleManager.setContext method but this object just has the test profile, not the config Map.

Thanks!

Comment: There is currently no built in way to pass data between them - you would have to do it manually likely using a `ThreadLocal`.

Comment: Thanks @geoand. Are all QuarkusTestResourceLifecycleManager in the same thread, then?

Comment: Yes, unless `parallel=true` is set on `QuarkusTestResource`